# Correct way to check for property change in design mode C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, properties, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

Ok, so I'm trying to run some code that modifies a UI when a user changes a custom control's dependency property value in design mode; but only when in design mode.

I've tried these approaches:

```
1.
public static DependencyProperty x = ...Register(..., new PropertyMetadata(null, changeMethod));

2.
set { SetValue(XProp, value); changeMethod(value); }

3.
var observable = x as INotifyPropertyChanged;
observable.PropertyChanged += ObservablePropertyChanged;
```

But all of them seem to have their own issues in that they either trigger errors or don't work at all.

So does anyone know what the correct way to listen to a dependency property change in design mode is, and if so can you give an example?

Comment: You can't modify a dp's setter as the framework only calls GetValue and SetValue directly. Instead you could declare a OnXPropPropertyChanged PropertyChanged method as described by Riccardo below. changeMethod(value); will never be called in the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to handle DependencyProperty changes is to:

. Declare the DependencyProperty:

```
public static DependencyProperty MyXProperty;
```

. Create the public get/set Property:

```
public string MyX
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MyXProperty); } //Supposing that the property type is string
    set { SetValue(MyXProperty, value); }
}
```

. Register the DependencyProperty in your static constructor:

```
static MyClass()
{
    MyXProperty= DependencyProperty.Register("MyX", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", OnMyXPropertyChanged));
}
```

. Declare the Property Changed Method:

```
private static void OnMyXPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    MyClass thisClass = d as MyClass ;
    //Do Something            
}
```

Please provide more information if you still can't find your solution.

Comment: +1 You beat me to it, was just about to post hehe ;) It's correct what you say here all of it. You can not modify the regular properties directly, as the framework will only call get GetValue() and SetValue() methods directly on any d.p. The solution is as you describe to add a DP Property Changed method.

Comment: Yes. You can simply write: 
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnMyXPropertyChanged) 
without declaring a default value.

Comment: @Riccardo You could ofc to cut down some code do a **public static DependencyProperty MyXProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyX", typeof(string),typeof(MyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("", OnMyXPropertyChanged));** directly to save some lines of codes though. :)